# hook_user_update() is invoked before saving the user account, not after

Tags: hooks, database

I created a module that implements `hook_user_update()`.
As far as I understand this method is called once a user has edited his data and this has been saved to the database.

The problem I notice is that it is not what really happens with my code: The code is called before.

```
function mymodule_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "database";

  mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
  @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
  $query = "select * from somewhere;";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $num = mysql_numrows($result);

  $myFile = "some_file.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
  $stringData = "now: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." Value is:".mysql_result($result,0);
  fwrite($fh, $stringData);
  fclose($fh);      
}
```

When I check the result at this point, the values are still the ones before saving the user account.
I thought it would be some kind of database cache but this is supposed to be deleted once you edit the table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, in Drupal 7 [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/7) first invokes `hook_user_presave()`, then saves the user account in the database, and invokes `hook_user_update()` or `hook_user_insert()`.
It is not possible that `hook_user_update()` is called before the user account has been saved.
`hook_entity_update()` and `hook_entity_insert()` are invoked right after `hook_user_update()` and `hook_user_insert()`. Eventual field updates should be executed with those hooks.

```
// Invoke hook_user_presave() for all modules.
user_module_invoke('presave', $edit, $account, $category);

// …

if (is_object($account) && !$account->is_new) {
  // ...
  $success = drupal_write_record('users', $account, 'uid');
  if ($success === FALSE) {
    // The query failed - better to abort the save than risk further
    // data loss.
    return FALSE;
  }

  // …

  user_module_invoke('update', $edit, $account, $category);
  module_invoke_all('entity_update', $account, 'user');
}
else {
  // …

  $success = drupal_write_record('users', $account);
  if ($success === FALSE) {
    // On a failed INSERT some other existing user's uid may be returned.
    // We must abort to avoid overwriting their account.
    return FALSE;
  }

  // …

  user_module_invoke('insert', $edit, $account, $category);
  module_invoke_all('entity_insert', $account, 'user');

  // …
}

// …
```

In Drupal 6, [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/6) invokes `hook_user('update')`, saves the user data in the database, and then invokes `hook_user('afer_update')`; if the user account didn't exist before, it saves the data in the database, and then invokes `hook_user('insert')`.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, But when I retrieve the data is not correct... I don't know, is quite weird...

Comment: Wait, I have extended the user profile with custom fields. It is possible that the workflow goes like: Save User > Hook_user_update > Store extra field values?

Comment: If you have custom fields added with the Field UI module, those fields should be updated with `hook_entity_update()`, which is executed after `hook_user_update()`.

Comment: The only thing unclear this article cleared up a little for me is what is the difference is in coding when in hook_presave using $account-­­­­­­­­­­­>data or $edit["variable_name"] ensures the account data is being saved as expected whereas in hook_update implementation , I always assumed account object had allready been been saved and any changes to account in this hook needed to be updated and possibly even saved in this hook, contrary to hook_user_presave.

Comment: when i use the hook_user_update with an insert query in theme's template.php file , it is not working for me. function garland_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
 db_insert('user_changes')->fields(array(
 'uid' => $account->uid,
 'changed' => time(),
 ))->execute();
 exit; 
}

Comment: @Ananth Themes cannot implement hooks, if not alter hooks. You cannot implement `hook_user_update()` in a theme, but you are allowed to implement `hook_menu_alter()` for example.